# How to send ETH directly from ERC721 (OpenZeppelin) contract to the PaymentSplitter contract?

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, openzeppelin

I have an openZeppelin ERC721 NFT contract (MyNFTPrice.sol) and also a separate PaymentSplitter contract.  My understanding is that these two contract need to be deployed separately.  My question is, how do I send the price of minting from my NFT contract (MyNFTPrice.sol) to the PaymentSplitter contract?  Currently, the price for minting an NFT resides in the MyNFTPrice.sol contract address.

MyNFTPrice.sol

```
 pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

 import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
 import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";
 import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
 import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";

contract MyNFTPrice is ERC721URIStorage {
using Counters for Counters.Counter;
Counters.Counter private _tokenIds;

constructor() public ERC721("MyNFTPrice", "NFTPRICE") {}


// Mint new NFT
function mintNFT(address recipient, string memory tokenURI) public payable  {

    require(msg.value >= 50000000000000000, "You need 0.05 ETH to mint the NFT"); 

    _tokenIds.increment();

    uint256 newItemId = _tokenIds.current();
    _mint(recipient, newItemId);
    _setTokenURI(newItemId, tokenURI);

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [transfer()](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.7/types.html#members-of-addresses) member of the `address payable`.

```
function mintNFT(address recipient, string memory tokenURI) public payable  {
    require(msg.value >= 50000000000000000, "You need 0.05 ETH to mint the NFT");

    // effectively redirects the `msg.value` to the `0x123` address
    payable(address(0x123)).transfer(msg.value);

    // ... rest of your code
}
```

Replace the `0x123` to the real address of the `PaymentSplitter`.

You can also store the address in a variable and change it when you need to. In this case, it's recommended to use an authorization mechanism, such as the [Ownable](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/access-control#ownership-and-ownable) pattern, so that only an authorized sender can change the value.

---

Since the `PaymentSplitter` is a contract, it needs to contain the [receive()](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.7/contracts.html#receive-ether-function) or [fallback()](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.7/contracts.html#fallback-function) `payable` function. Otherwise the `PaymentSplitter` as the receiver would reject the incoming payment and effectively cause the whole `mintNFT()` transaction to revert.

```
contract PaymentSplitter {
    receive() external payable {
        // can be empty
    }
}
```